# Get color of a point on the canvas

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit

Is it possible to get the color (rgb-value and transparency) of a point (x/y-coordinate) from the canvas? Example: I draw some  figures and text on a canvas and later I want to get the color of a point at a specific coordinate.

The solution should be independent whether the canvas is visible on screen or not. And it should work independently from the operating system.

I didn't found any solution on the web. That's why I assume that this is not possible. Am I right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The canvas isn't very pixel-based, and provides no API for doing this.

But if you've got the [tkimg](https://sourceforge.net/projects/tkimg/) package installed, you can use that to do a [screengrab of the canvas](http://wiki.tcl.tk/1404#pagetoc36da88f2) and then [fetch the pixel value](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TkCmd/photo.htm#M29) out of that.

```
package require Img

# Get the data into an image
set screengrab [image create photo -format window -data $theCanvas]
# Read the pixel data out of the grabbed image
set pixeldata [$screengrab get $x $y]
# Get rid of the grabbed data once you're done
image delete $screengrab
```

Note that the coordinates concerned will be viewport coordinates, not canvas internal coordinates: if you've scrolled the canvas, you'll have to offset as necessary.

Comment: Thank you very much. I added `tkwait visibility $theCanvas` and `update` before starting the screengrab.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct, tk does not provide any way to get the color of a specific pixel on a canvas.